# Best methodology for developing c# long running processor apps

Tags: background, long-integer, task, worker, runner

I have several different c# worker applications that run various continuous tasks: sending emails from queue, importing new orders from website database to orders database, making database backups and restores, running data processing for OLTP -> OLAP, and other related tasks. Before, I released these as windows services, but currently I release them as regular console applications. They are all based on a common task runner framework I created, and I am happy with that, however I am not sure what is the best way to deploy these types of applications. I like the console version because it is quick and easy, and it is possible to quickly see program activity and output. The downside is that the worker computer has several console screens running and it gets messy. On the other hand the service method seems to take to long to deploy and I have to go through event logs to see messages. What are some experiences/comments on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the console app approach. I typically have things set up so I can pass a switch like -unattended that suppresses the console screen.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Service would be a good choice, it runs in the background no matter if you close current session, also you can configure it to start automatically after windows restart when performing a patches update on the server. You can log important messages to event viewer or database table.

Answer (score 1):

For a thing like this, the standard way of doing it is with Windows services. You want the service to run on the network account so it won't require a logged in user.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a special account for each service you write, giving it just the permissions you want rather than latching onto an available account as that's a potential security hole.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on something a few years ago that had similar issues.  Logically I needed a service, but sometimes I needed to see what was going on and generally I wanted a history.  So I developed a service which did the work, any time it wanted to log, it called to it's subscribers (implemented as an observer pattern).

The service registered it's own data logger (writing to a database) and at run time, the user could run a GUI which connected to the service using remoting to become a live listener!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to vote for Windows Services.  It's going to get to be a real pain managing those console applications.

Windows Service deployment is easy: after the initial install, you just turn them off and do an XCOPY.  No need to run any complicated installers.  It's only semi-complicated the first time, and even then it's just

```
installutil MyApp.exe
```

Configre the services to run under a domain account for the best security and easiest interop with other machines.

Use a combination of event logs (with Error, Warning, and Information) for important notifications, and just dump verbose logging to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the best of all worlds and use something like:
http://topshelf-project.com/

It will allow you to run your program as command line or a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to your applications or not, but when I have some console applications that are not dependent on user input or they are the kind of applications that just do their job and quit, I run such programs on a virtual server, this way I don't see a screen popping up when I'm working, and virtual servers are easy to create and restart.

Answer (score 0):

We regularly use windows services as the background processes. I don't like command-line apps as you need to be logged into the server for them to run. Services run in the background all the time (assuming they're auto-start). They're also trivial to install w/the sc.exe command-line tool that's in windows. I like it better than the bloat-ware that is installutil.exe. Of course installutil does more, but I don't need what it does. I just want to register my service.

We've also created a infrastructure where we have a generic service .exe that loads .DLLs based on an interface definition, so adding a new "service" is as simple as dropping in a new DLL and restarting the service host.

However, we started to move away from services. The problem we have with them is that they lock up the DLLs (for obvious reasons) so it's a pain to upgrade them. We need to stop, upgrade and then restart. Not hard, but additional steps. Instead we're moving to special "pages" in our asp.net apps that run the actual background jobs we need done. There's still a service, but all it does it invoke the asp.net pages so it doesn't lock up any of our DLLs. Then we can replace the DLLs in the asp.net bin directory and normal asp.net rules for app-domain restart kick in.